# Prerender not detecting the token with Nginx

Tags: angularjs, node.js, nginx, prerender

We have an angular app, and we are trying to implement [prerender.io](https://prerender.io/) for SEO purposes.

We cached all the url's using the sitemap and followed the official Nginx tutorial: https://gist.github.com/thoop/8165802

But prerender.io keeps displaying this message:
**We haven't seen a request with your Prerender token yet.**

You can check our Nginx code here:

```
server {
  listen 443;
  server_name example.com;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/example.com.ssl.access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/example.com.ssl.error.log debug;

  #SSL conf

  location / {

    try_files $uri @prerender;

    if ($request_filename ~* ^.*?/([^/]*?)$)
    {
        set $filename $1;
    }

    if ($filename ~* ^.*?\.(eot)|(ttf)|(woff)$){
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
    }

    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP            $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header   Host                   $http_host;
    proxy_set_header   X-NginX-Proxy    true;
    proxy_set_header   Connection "";
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_cache one;
    proxy_cache_key sfs$request_uri$scheme;

    proxy_pass http://example.com;
  }

  location @prerender {
      #proxy_set_header X-Prerender-Token YOUR_TOKEN;

      set $prerender 0;
      if ($http_user_agent ~* "baiduspider|twitterbot|facebookexternalhit|rogerbot|linkedinbot|embedly|quora link preview|showyoubot|outbrain|pinterest|slackbot|vkShare|W3C_Validator") {
          set $prerender 1;
      }
      if ($args ~ "_escaped_fragment_") {
          set $prerender 1;
      }
      if ($http_user_agent ~ "Prerender") {
          set $prerender 0;
      }
      if ($uri ~* "\.(js|css|xml|less|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|pdf|doc|txt|ico|rss|zip|mp3|rar|exe|wmv|doc|avi|ppt|mpg|mpeg|tif|wav|mov|psd|ai|xls|mp4|m4a|swf|dat|dmg|iso|flv|m4v|torrent|ttf|woff|svg|eot)") {
          set $prerender 0;
      }

      #resolve using Google's DNS server to force DNS resolution and prevent caching of IPs
      resolver 8.8.8.8;

      if ($prerender = 1) {

          #setting prerender as a variable forces DNS resolution since nginx caches IPs and doesnt play well with load balancing
          set $prerender "service.prerender.io";
          rewrite .* /$scheme://$host$request_uri? break;
          proxy_pass http://$prerender;
      }
      if ($prerender = 0) {
          rewrite .* /index.html break;
      }
  }

}
```

We tried different solutions from [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com) to similar problems but nothing works...

Comment: I might have missed this yesterday when I answered this, but you also have your token commented out: #proxy_set_header X-Prerender-Token YOUR_TOKEN; Make sure you remove the # from that line

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that is a copy paste error :) We don't have the token commented, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm wondering if the try_files isn't working here for some reason. Can you try putting the prerender config inline instead?

```
server {
  listen 443;
  server_name example.com;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/example.com.ssl.access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/example.com.ssl.error.log debug;

  #SSL conf

  location / {

    if ($request_filename ~* ^.*?/([^/]*?)$)
    {
        set $filename $1;
    }

    if ($filename ~* ^.*?\.(eot)|(ttf)|(woff)$){
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
    }

    #proxy_set_header X-Prerender-Token YOUR_TOKEN;

    set $prerender 0;
    if ($http_user_agent ~* "baiduspider|twitterbot|facebookexternalhit|rogerbot|linkedinbot|embedly|quora link preview|showyoubot|outbrain|pinterest|slackbot|vkShare|W3C_Validator") {
        set $prerender 1;
    }
    if ($args ~ "_escaped_fragment_") {
        set $prerender 1;
    }
    if ($http_user_agent ~ "Prerender") {
        set $prerender 0;
    }
    if ($uri ~* "\.(js|css|xml|less|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|pdf|doc|txt|ico|rss|zip|mp3|rar|exe|wmv|doc|avi|ppt|mpg|mpeg|tif|wav|mov|psd|ai|xls|mp4|m4a|swf|dat|dmg|iso|flv|m4v|torrent|ttf|woff|svg|eot)") {
        set $prerender 0;
    }

    #resolve using Google's DNS server to force DNS resolution and prevent caching of IPs
    resolver 8.8.8.8;

    if ($prerender = 1) {

        #setting prerender as a variable forces DNS resolution since nginx caches IPs and doesnt play well with load balancing
        set $prerender "service.prerender.io";
        rewrite .* /$scheme://$host$request_uri? break;
        proxy_pass http://$prerender;
    }

    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP            $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header   Host                   $http_host;
    proxy_set_header   X-NginX-Proxy    true;
    proxy_set_header   Connection "";
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_cache one;
    proxy_cache_key sfs$request_uri$scheme;

    proxy_pass http://example.com;
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but seems that doesn't work either :( It keeps displaying this message: We haven't seen a request with your Prerender token yet.

Comment: Fixed! We added 'Googlebot' in the $http_user_agent if :)

Comment: You don't want to check Googlebot by their user agent because that could get you penalized for cloaking. If you put <meta name="fragment" content="!"> in the <head> of your pages then Google, Bing, and other crawlers will crawl the ?_escaped_fragment_= URL.

Comment: Thanks for the info! We put the meta tag on the <head> and when we do put the ?_escaped_fragment_ on the URL it charge properly. But we 'Fetched' the web with Google Webmaster tools and it not shows the rendered html... Seems that google is not crawling the ?_escaped_fragment_= URL

Comment: Fetch as Google has a known bug where they don't automatically check for the <meta name="fragment" content="!"> tag, so with Fetch as Google you want to enter the ?_escaped_fragment_= URL manually. The real Googlebot will see the fragment meta tag and re-request the ?_escaped_fragment_= URL on their own.

Comment: Thanks for helping guys, you are awesome :)

Comment: Happy to help! :D